# Android setOnClickListener crashes my app on avd

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to android dev, I created a new project with `NavigationDrawer` activity, I use Android Studio. The problem is when I add a button and create **OnClickListener**, the app crushes, but without it, it launches fine. Please look at my code below.
I tried adding **setContentView(View)** but doesn't help

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //comes by default
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main); //added by me, but doesnt help

    //referencing my button
    btnTest =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTest);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    //my event listeners
    //when i highlight the below code everythin works..these block cause the crash
     btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });


}
```

I know others have had these issue and solved it, but I'm not able to solve mine, please help, Thank You

Comment: Please provided the LogCat

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{za.co.mybroker.mybroker/za.co.mybroker.mybroker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: in which layout `btnTest`?

Comment: Did you try to delete the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`?

Comment: Hi btnTest is in fragment_main.xml

Comment: remove the first setContentView()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //comes by default
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main); //added by me, but doesnt help
```

Don't call `setContentView` twice. The one that "comes by default" is provided for your convenience when the IDE is generating the `Activity` class, if you don't need it, delete it.

Secondly, you are setting a fragment layout as `View` for your `Activity`. So unless `R.id.btnTest` is included in that layout, `btnTest` will be null, hence causing a `NullPointerException` when calling `setOnClickListener`.

delete this :

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

and here

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

make sure you have a layout file for your `Activity` that is named `activity_main.xml` or replace that reference with the name of your layout file.

**EDIT** : I'm guessing you chose the option in AS to generate a placeholder in your Activity and a Fragment to be added to it. You need to handle the button in the Fragment class, and more importantly, you need to add the Fragment to your Activity.

In your `Activity` (in `OnCreate`, after the setup of the nav drawer) :

```
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment(); // replace ExampleFragment by your Fragment's class name
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(CONTENT_VIEW_ID, newFragment).commit(); // CONTENT_VIEW_ID is the id of the View in your Activity that should contain the Fragment.
```

And then in your `Fragment`, move this to `onActivityCreated` :

```
btnTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
});
```

You will need to inflate `R.layout.fragment_main` in `onCreateView` in your `Fragment`, and get a reference to `btnTest` from the `View` you inflate.

Comment: I tried with on setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  no luck still.
when i start a new project, 
1. activity_main.xml
2.fragment_main.xml
gets created, and btnTest is in fragment_main.xml

Comment: Thanks for ur guys help, after long research i finally solved it..and yes @2Dee, you are 100% right.

Comment: Cool, well done ;) May I ask you to accept/upvote answers that helped you, to mark the question as closed ? Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Without Logcat I would say that your problem is one of the following:

1. `btnTest` is not defined in your ActivityLayout (activity_main). If this is the case check your XML.
2. Is your `btnTest` inside your `Fragment`? If so you should put the `OnClickListener` in your `Fragment` class instead of your `Activity` class.

BTW, the second `setContentView` doesnt make any sense you should use only one.

Hope it helps